# ConsumerRecord contain key value inside double quote ""xxxxxxxxxxxxxx""in apache spring kafka

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Using spring Kafka to product and listen to the request, The key value in inside the ""

## Producer code

```
public record ProductProducer(ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, Object, Object> _replyTemplate,
                              ) implements IProductProducer {
     public ProductViewModel Update(ProductViewModel product, String id) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
            RequestReplyFuture<String, Object, Object> future =
                    this._replyTemplate.sendAndReceive(new ProducerRecord<>(ProductTopicConstants.UPDATE_PRODUCT,0, id,product));
            LOG.info(future.getSendFuture().get(kafkaConstants.kafkaTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS).getRecordMetadata().toString());
            Product productDb = (Product) future.get(kafkaConstants.kafkaTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS).value();
            return new ProductViewModel();
        }}
```

## Listener

```
@KafkaListener(id = ProductTopicConstants.UPDATE_PRODUCT, topics = ProductTopicConstants.UPDATE_PRODUCT,
            containerFactory = "addUpdateProductContainerFactory")
    @SendTo
    public Object UpdateProduct(ConsumerRecord<String, ProductViewModel> productViewModel) {
        String id = productViewModel.key();
        logger.info("Listening to update product with id :", id);
        return new Product();
    }
```

The key value is inside "" as shown below

[image]

## consumer factory

```
 @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactoryGetDeleteProduct() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(),
                new StringDeserializer(),
                new JsonDeserializer<>(String.class));
    }
```

I have the below configuration

```
producer:
      key-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
    consumer:
      key-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer




@Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, this.bootstrapAddress.getKafka().getBootstrapAddress());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        return props;
    }
```

Comment: What is the question? It looks like you are somehow encoding to JSON a value that has already been encoded.

Comment: The question is that the Key value, I am getting inside the "" as you can see in the screenshot, as per your comment encoded to JSON. But I have no idea where that is happening

Comment: Nobody can help you with the information you have provided - you need to run in a debugger on the producer and consumer side to see what's happening - I would start debugging in the serializer on the producer side and deserializer on the consumer side.

Answer (score 0):

My serialization and deserialization was doing JSON parser changing to string does the work

```
producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
consumer:
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```